# What is the OrderedHiddenHttpMethodFilter objective? Can I disable this filter?

Tags: spring-boot

let see breakdown table from newrelic monitor the performance
[image]

can I disable this Filter (20.6 ms response time)

spring boot version **1.5.3.RELEASE**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes it is safe to disable unless your front end “fakes” methods other than GET and POST with a hidden `__method` parameter or other such nonsense. You can read the description of the filter here: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/master/spring-web/src/main/java/org/springframework/web/filter/HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java